# TFS database project for both Azure SQL database and on premises with multiple filegroups

Tags: tfs, azure-sql-database

I am working on a project to replicate an application that currently runs on premises to an Azure SQL Database.  For the foreseeable future, the application will have to run both on site and on Azure.  The project is stored in TFS, and multiple filegroups are specified.  Development is ongoing.  Is there a way I can maintain this as one project in source control, given that Azure SQL databases only have a primary filegroup?  I feel like I can't be the first person in this situation, but I haven't found a decent solution yet.

I'm fine with the Azure database only running on primary, but that is not an option for the local database.  This is not for a single deployment, I would like to continue to deploy changes both locally and to Azure from source control.  I may be asking for too much here, I just really really want to avoid dual maintenance, when there are a number of teams involved.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- Add manual SQL Statements to setup Filegroups on your on-premises SQL Server that don't run against SQL Azure
- Use a new feature of Azure named [SQL Managed Instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-options-to-modernize-your-application-with-azure-sql-database/). This is fully managed SQL Server instance running in Azure that supports all features of SQL Server such as filegroups. Don't go installing your own SQL Server on IaaS. That's not necessary anymore with this new feature.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use multiple filegroups in Azure SQL Database. If you want to move your database to the cloud and keep the ability to use multiple filegroups, please consider setting an [Azure VM with SQL Server on it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-iaas-overview). Another option would be to change your application so that it does not use SQL filegroups.

As for the replication, please consider [SQL Server replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication) or [Azure Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync). Azure Data Sync requires an Azure SQL database. It is slower than SQL Server replication but it can handle conflicts.